# Pandas: Get all ids that have more than one corresponding value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting with a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
userId | preference
1      | coffee
2      | cake 
2      | tea
3      | tea
3      | tea
3      | tea
4      | apple
4      | tea
```

I need to transform the above into this:

```
userId | preference
2      | cake 
2      | tea
4      | apple
4      | tea
```

Note userId 1 and userId 3 were dropped because they only had one unique preference. I would only want userIds that have 2 or more unique preferences to remain. I've been stuck on this. Tried using `.grouby` but getting nowhere

Comment: `df.groupby('userId').filter(lambda x :len(x)>1)`

Answer (score 2):

Get the count of unique values per userId, if it is greater than 1, keep, else discard.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('userId').preference.transform('nunique').gt(1)]
Out[26]: 
   userId preference
1       2       cake
2       2        tea
6       4      apple
7       4        tea
```

Answer (score 1):

Group wise filter would also work for your case it seems

```
df.groupby('userId').filter(lambda x: x['preference'].nunique()>1)
```

Out:

```
userId  |   preference
1   2   |   cake
2   2   |   tea
6   4   |   apple
7   4   |   tea
```

Comment: i'm not sure your output matches OP's

Comment: got the point, just made changes @sammywemmy :)